# Unanswered Question

Tags: discussion, questions

What should I do when I have a question that coincides with a question that was never answered in the past? For example, someone had asked the same question but resolved it, or the question page doesn't really have an answer. Should I bump it with a comment, or re-ask?

Comment: 1. Comments don't bump questions. Edits and answers do. 2. You can put a bounty on the original question. 3. You can ask another question if it is not exactly the same one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say that you should read the original question carefully and try to understand why it was never answered. Was it missing information? Did the OP never respond to requests for more information?

Then I believe that you should post a new question. Feel free to reference the original, but go ahead and ask the question.

But *this* time, make sure that your question is better than the original, so that you get an answer.